# Rsync from Mac OS to synology with btrfs having issues with file and directories that contain umlauts and similar characters

Tags: macos, rsync, synology, apfs

I want to copy a folder from my local Mac (Catalina with APFS) to my Synology (btrfs filesystem) on my local network.

And all files that have an umlaut in it (ö,ä,ü,....) gets in trouble somehow. First he is deleting the file in the destination and then he copies the same file over again. I know this is due to some rsync issue with Mac OS old version and the UTF encoding.

I updated rsync on my Mac already.

```
which rsync
/opt/local/bin/rsync

rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31
```

and this is the command I am using to copy the folder..

```
rsync -zuvar --delete --progress --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8 --exclude ".DS_Store" source destination
```

But still he always deletes those files and folders with umlauts and then copy them all again.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Share the output -> you ran it with -v...  especially the parts for files with umlaut

Comment: deleting Programming/tätäta.py
deleting Programming/tätäta Kopie.py
deleting Programming/tätäta
Programming/
Programming/tätäta
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=2/6)
Programming/tätäta Kopie.py
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=1/6)
Programming/tätäta.py
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, to-chk=0/6)

Comment: Are you using ssh or is the destination mounted by nfs? I.e. is your destination of form *remotehost:/directory* or not?

Comment: the NAS drive is mounted with smb. No I don't use ssh I just use /Volumes/Backup.... something like this

Comment: What version of rsync is on the destination?

Comment: Here's another [similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/397420/294707) which has an accepted reply saying they copied to cifs (smb) ok. If you remove the `--delete` does it still re-copy the umlauted files?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to stop using iconv.
It is okay that there are multiple valid encodings for umlauts. Apple probably tries to simplify some scenarios by forcing a single encoding approach. By using iconv you may be, as you suggest, confusing rsync.

Comment: The same happens without using conv... I just came to use iconv because I was experience problems and was searching for a solution. But doesn't matter with iconv on or off it doesn't work

Comment: Can you not just run Rsync directly to the Synology box rather than via SMB mount on OSX?